# Watson Conversation API malfunctioning when called from Windows?

Tags: api, watson-conversation

I’ve been playing with Watson Conversation API and it seems to be working fine when called from Mac, but not when called from Windows machine. I tried making those API-calls from Postman and Kinetise on both systems. On Windows the response I get is `404 - {”error”:”Resource not found”}`.

I’m guessing the issue might be about dashes in `“version”=“2017-05-26”`, because if I make a call without this parameter, I get exactly the same response on both operating systems, which is “Missing ‘version’ query parameter”.

Do you know anything about this issue or can point me to where I could find help?

Here is my query:

```
POST /conversation/api/v1/workspaces/3916c79e-b94b-476e-8fc8-f16c9a43f826/message?version=2017-05-26 HTTP/1.1
Host: gateway.watsonplatform.net
Authorization: Basic XXXX
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36
Accept-Encoding: gzip
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 738

{
  "input": {
    "text": “hello"
  },
  "alternate_intents": true
}
```

Comment: REST is language agnostic, as long as you are sending the same request it should work on Windows and Mac. The error you are getting is because the `workspace_id` doesn't exist. Try to do a GET to `/v1/workspaces` and see the result

Comment: OMG... (facepalm). You are right. I made a typo... twice... THANK YOU!